# What's the rationaIe behind using sans-serif font in questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Searched for this question on meta but couldn't beIieve it hadn't been asked, so l'm asking.

Everytime l see something like "l-theanine" a red haze cIouds my vision. ls that "[eye]-theanine"? "[EII]-theanine"? "[one]-theanine"? Who knows, untiI you paste it in a text editor and change to a sensibIe font? Not that much work reaIIy, but seems absoIuteIy unnecessary if you ask me.

l'm just curious to know what possibIe benefit this achieves over serif fonts, which are 100% unambiguous in this respect.

(To prove my point, every capital "l" in this post is a lowercase I and vice versa)

Comment: This is a site-specific concern. Some sites (Mathematics, Christianity, Electrical Engineering)... use serif fonts. What site do you have in mind?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question about fonts on general, and it is not specific to the Stack Exchange network. A more suitable site may be [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: (Also, if you don't like the font, you can use a userstyle installed to your web browser.)

Comment: @900sit-upsaday stackoverflow, biology, travel, to name a few

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sans-serif fonts, and in particular Arial (together with its elder sister Helvetica, on systems that have it) is a de-facto standard for web pages that have no particular reason to set some other font. The background is that especially on older devices, Times New Roman—which used to be the common *browser* default, and largely still is—suffers from legibility problems: on small-resolution screens, the serifs don’t work the way they do in print.

As of now, there are not many alternatives. Many people are used to seeing Arial and would take Times New Roman as outdated. There are surely many better fonts, but none that are available across systems. Besides, opinions differ. Arial is simply common and familiar to most people.

Comment: Aha, hadn't considered legibility